# lucene 4.6 concurrent flushing

Tags: search, concurrency, lucene, indexing, lucene.net

I have read http://blog.trifork.com/2011/04/01/gimme-all-resources-you-have-i-can-use-them/ which mentions concurrent flushing, however when I tried looking into api of version 4.5.1 and 4.6.1 there are no such function and I cannot find any sample code either. The class DocumentsWriterPerThread is not in 4.5.1-4.6.1

Can anyone please provide some info on this issue? It would be great if a sample code provided as well to get me start up.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[DocumentsWriterPerThread](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/4.5.0/org/apache/lucene/index/DocumentsWriterPerThread.java#DocumentsWriterPerThread) certainly is out there in Lucene 4.5, though to the best of my knowledge, it's not really something most users would be expected to monkey with.

As far as how to use Concurrent Flushing, you already are.  The change went out with Lucene 4.0, see [LUCENE-3023](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3023).

If you are not seeing this speed improvement is some way (not sure what problem you are observing), as stated by Michael McCandless, in his [article on the topic](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/05/265-indexing-speedup-with-lucenes.html):

> Remember this change only helps you if you have concurrent hardware, you use enough threads for indexing and there's no other bottleneck (for example, in the content source that provides the documents)

Comment: DocumentsWriterPerThread is not in 4.5.1 if im not wrong, because I didnt find it somehow. In addition, how could we use it in coding?

Comment: You are mistaken.  DocumentsWriterPerThread is there, in Lucene Core, at `org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread`.  Perhaps what is confusing you is that it isn't a public class.  It's package private.  As I said, you aren't really intended to be messing with it.

Comment: so if it's not supposed to be used manually, does it mean when we code in multithreads (multiple index writers), lucene will automaticlaly apply this new concurrent flushing mechnicism?

Comment: What it means is that you go on adding documents to Lucene and it will use DocumentWriterPerThread (More than one DWPTs) for indexing documents concurrently. You can not have multiple IndexWriters. There is one IndexWriter but one IW uses many DWPTs.